# Inno Setup - Check if Uninstall is running in silent mode

Tags: inno-setup, pascal, pascalscript

I'm looking for something like [WizardSilent](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_wizardsilent), but for uninstall. Is there one?

Comment: Did you try WizardSilent for uninstall? The documentation sometimes says "Setup" but actually means "Setup and Uninstall".

Comment: Yup. Results in error `Cannot call "WizardSilent" during UnInstall`.

Answer (score 4):

It's [UninstallSilent](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_uninstallsilent). Why didn't I give this a try?

Comment: I think you meant to link here: http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_uninstallsilent